# Golang Base64 encoded SHA256 digest of the user’s password

Tags: hash, go, cryptography, sha256

I am attempting to complete the Top Code Go Learning Challenges as a vehicle to learn go.  I'm currently working on their [Simple API Web Server problem](https://www.topcoder.com/challenge-details/30046011/?type=develop).  Part of that problem calls for you to encrypt a password string as such "‘{SHA256}’ + Base64 encoded SHA256 digest of the user’s password"

I've used the following code to do this, but the results don't match the test case provided.

```
import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "crypto/sha256"
)

func encrtyptPasswords(password string) string {
    h := sha256.New()
    return "{SHA256}" + 
       string(base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum([]byte(password))))
}
```

For an input of abcd1234 it should encrypt to: {SHA256}6c7nGrky_ehjM40Ivk3p3-OeoEm9r7NCzmWexUULaa4=

But I get {SHA256}YWJjZDEyMzTjsMRCmPwcFJr79MiZb7kkJ65B5GSbk0yklZkbeFK4VQ== instead.  I suspect I'm using the encryption libraries wrong, but I'm not sure what I should be using as this seems to be the standard library method of encryption to SHA256.

Comment: Note that SHA256 is a *terribly insecure* way to hash (it's a hash algorithm, not an encryption algorithm) user passwords. You should be using a key derivation function (KDF) designed for this purpose. bcrypt (https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) and scrypt (https://github.com/elithrar/simple-scrypt) are the de facto standards here.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, really just programming to spec on this to match the provided test data. The provided design also stores passwords in the clear on a JSON file.

Comment: Yeah I've contacted them in the hopes they will use a more suitable construct. It sets up newbies for failure in the long run as lessons like this come across as "authoritative".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're misusing the `Sum` method. The [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) for the `hash.Hash` interface clearly say that

> Sum *appends* the current hash to b and returns the resulting slice.

(Emphasis added.)

You need to either write the data to the hash and use `h.Sum` like this

```
h.Write([]byte(password))
b := h.Sum(nil)
```

or just use [`sha256.Sum256`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#Sum256)

```
h := sha256.Sum256([]byte(password))
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/oFBePRQzhN.

Comment: FWIW `b := h.Sum(nil)` would also work for your first example.

Comment: This is great. Just have one question, are the result already on digest?